# Get deta datewise in hive/impala sql,

Tags: python, python-3.x, impala

I have one column collection_date :- data type timestamp, having date time entry in yyyy-mm-dd hr:mm:ss but i am trying to fetch the record day wise, so I have to ignore hr:mm:ss, how can I apply in where apply only date in impala sql

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the time from timestamp using below function. And this is a timestamp too so you can compare with the date.

```
select trunc(now(),'DDD') a;

a   
2021-09-02 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_TIMESTAMP(NOW(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

Comment: This will return string so you may not effectively compare with any date column to pull data. But you know the requirements.